# Ember.Controller doesn't exist?

Tags: ember.js

I'm just getting started with Ember. I'm a  little confused on some things, as the guides on the main site seem to indicate different ways of working.

In the main docs (http://emberjs.com/documentation/), it indicates that a controller should just extend an ordinary Ember object like this:

```
Ember.Object.extend();
```

Which works fine for me.

Then in the guide to using Routing (http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/) it suggests that there is a Controller object type that you can extend:

```
Ember.Controller.extend();
```

This doesn't work for me, and if I simply try to console.log Ember.Controller, its undefined.

I'm using Ember version 0.9.8.1.

Should I worry about this, or should I just carry on with extending Objects as my controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.9.8.1 is aging, and unfortunately even the guides on the site are ahead of it -- use latest (at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/downloads) to keep up with the most current best practices.

**Update**: 1.0-pre is out ([emberjs.com](http://www.emberjs.com)), so that is the best to use. The docs / guides have been brought up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I think @pauldechov means the specific "latest" build which you can find here:   https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/downloads

But also keep in mind that the documentation and "latest" are not always in sync.

Comment: That's correct. As of just now there is a 1.0-pre version on there too (though it still says 0.9.8.1 at the top of the file as of this moment)